# ansible loop on group nodes with_items and avoid ssh

Tags: ansible, ansible-2.x, ansible-inventory, ansible-facts

Team, I have below task where I want to use the node name in my kubectl command but ansible is doing ssh to those nodes. where as i don't want ssh to happen at all since kubectl command is going to be run locally and not on the host. how to modify task such that it just uses the node names in its kubeclt command?

```
        shell: kubectl get node {{ item }} -o json
        ignore_errors: no
        register: node_info
        failed_when: node_info.rc == 0
        delegate_to: "{{ item }}"
        with_items: "{{ groups['kube-gpu-node'] }}"
      - debug:
          var: node_info
```

output:

```
TASK [: Alternate to K8s_facts use Command] ****************************************************************************************************************************
failed: [localhost] (item=node2) => {"ansible_loop_var": "item", "item": "node2", "msg": "Failed to connect to the host via ssh: ssh: Could not resolve hostname node2.team.try.com.net: Name or service not known", "unreachable": true}
failed: [localhost] (item=node1) => {"ansible_loop_var": "item", "item": "node1", "msg": "Failed to connect to the host via ssh: ssh: Could not resolve hostname node1.team.try.com.net: Name or service not known", "unreachable": true}
fatal: [localhost]: UNREACHABLE! => {"changed": false, "msg": "All items completed", "results": [{"ansible_loop_var": "item", "item": "node2", "msg": "Failed to connect to the host via ssh: ssh: Could not resolve hostname node2.team.try.com.net: Name or service not known", "unreachable": true}, {"ansible_loop_var": "item", "item": "node1", "msg": "Failed to connect to the host via ssh: ssh: Could not resolve hostname node1.team.try.com.net: Name or service not known", "unreachable": true}]}
```

output expected: sample..

```
{
    "apiVersion": "v1",
    "kind": "Node",
    "metadata": {
        "annotations": {
            "csi.volume.kubernetes.io/nodeid": "{\"com.nvidia.csi.vdisk\":\"mldgx1k8s0117d\",\"csi-vdiskplugin\":\"mldgx1k8s0117d\"}",
            "kubeadm.alpha.kubernetes.io/cri-socket": "/var/run/dockershim.sock",
            "node.alpha.kubernetes.io/ttl": "0",
            "volumes.kubernetes.io/controller-managed-attach-detach": "true"
        },
```

Answer (score 0):

Figured out : I should not use delegate_to

```
        shell: kubectl get node {{ item }} -o json
        ignore_errors: no
        register: node_info
        failed_when: node_info.rc != 0
        with_items: "{{ groups['kube-gpu-node'] }}"
      - debug:
          var: node_info
```